# 3D-plot region between two surfaces

Tags: plotting, regions

I'd like to 3D-plot the region between the infinite cone $z=1-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $z = 1-y, z \ge 0$ in *Mathematica* 10. Also I'd like to know if there is any way (in *Mathematica*) to calculate the volume of the region above.
Thanks a lot

P.S. This is the region I tried to plot from a book.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `ImplicitRegion` and `Volume`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried ImplicitRegion but i can't get the correct plot. could you write here the exact input please?

Answer (score 3):

I started this mainly for fun, I guess, but it makes a nice, sharp plot.  The region needs to have a nice [`CylindricalDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html).
[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) will compute this, too.  It makes a predictable format that can be rewritten easily into code for other standard *Mathematica* functions.

```
CylindricalDecomposition[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y, {y, x, z}]
Reduce[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y, {y, x, z}]
Reduce[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y, z]
(*  all give the same answer:
  0 < y < 1 && -Sqrt[y - y^2] < x < Sqrt[y - y^2] && 1 - y < z < 1 - x^2 - y^2
*)
```

This example gives a simple cylindrical decomposition.  Often a region can be written only as a sum of such cylindrical regions.  `CylindricalDecomposition` returns the "sum" in the form

```
Or[cd1, cd2,...]
```

This case, too, is easy to handle (e.g. replace `Or` by `List`, perhaps), but how to do it depends on the application.  So I will leave it to the interested reader to explore.

Code:

```
ClearAll[cdapply];
cdapply[f_, argsfn_: List, opts___] := 
  HoldPattern[
    And[_[u1_, ___, u_Symbol /; Context[u] === "Global`", ___, u2_],
     _[v1_, ___, v_Symbol /; Context[v] === "Global`", ___, v2_], _[w1_, ___, w2_]]
    ] :> f[argsfn[w1, w2], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}, opts];
```

The need for `___` between the arguments is because there are two ways to express an inequality $a < b < c$:

```
Less[a, b, c]
Inequality[a, Less, b, Less, c]
```

The pattern matches both, but the code does assume the inequality is `Less` (or `LessEqual`).

OP's example, with three views of the result:

```
cd = Reduce[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y, z];
cd /. cdapply[Plot3D, List, PlotPoints -> 50];
GraphicsRow[{%, %, %}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cd /. cdapply[Integrate, #2 - #1 &]
(*  π/32  *)
```

Here's what code the replacement rule is constructing:

```
cad /. cdapply[Inactive@Plot3D, List, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cad /. cdapply[Inactive[Integrate], #2 - #1 &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could adapt the replacement rule to handle functions like `Integrate` that allow three or more parameters as arguments.

```
ClearAll[cdapplyAll];
cdapplyAll[f_, argsfn_: (1 &), opts___] := 
  HoldPattern[
    And[_[u1_, ___, u_Symbol /; Context[u] === "Global`", ___, u2_],
     _[v1_, ___, v_Symbol /; Context[v] === "Global`", ___, v2_],
     _[w1_, ___, w_Symbol /; Context[w] === "Global`", ___, w2_]]
    ] :> f[argsfn[{u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}, {w, w1, w2}],
           {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}, {w, w1, w2}, opts];

cd /. cdapplyAll[Integrate]
(*  π/32  *)

cad /. cdapplyAll[Inactive[Integrate]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot3D[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[
          If[z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0 && z > 1 - y, 1, 0],
          {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

${\pi \over 32}$

Alternatively:

```
myRegion = 
  ImplicitRegion[0 <= z < 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z > 1 - y , {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[myRegion, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
RegionMeasure[myRegion]
```

${\pi \over 32}$

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot David, that helped me a lot :)

Comment: @ConCarayiannis  As I said, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).  It's the SE way to say thanks, as well.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[1 - y <= z <= 1 - x^2 - y^2 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];

Volume[reg]

(*  Pi/32  *)

Show[
 Plot3D[1 - x^2 - y^2,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle ->
   Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.4]]],
 Plot3D[1 - y,
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle ->
   Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.4]]],
 RegionPlot3D[reg,
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotPoints -> 100],
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"})]
```

[image]